# In angularJS I want Insert a Token, into a http header

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, factory

In the first step, I make a $http POST request who returs a Json with the field 'access_token':

```
  angular    
   .module('obparticularesmx')
   .controller('inicio2', inicio2);

   function inicio2($scope, $rootScope, $state, $http){

       $http({
           method:'POST',
           url:'https://example.token-services.com/token',
           data : {
              client_id: "1561a116-7bde-4967-8471-8d6fb62511fa"
            },
           headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x­www­urlencoded;'
           }
       }).success(function(data) {

       $scope.token = data.access_token;
       });
   }
```

Then, I use a factory in order to put that token into the header:

```
    .factory('httpRequestInterceptor', function ($rootScope) {
      return {
        request: function (config) {
          config.headers = {'Authorization':'Bearer ' + $rootScope.token}
      return config;
    }
  };
})
```

But when I send, in the Authorization entry, I see a Undefined value:

```
Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
**Authorization** Bearer undefined
Host particulares-gw-obparticularesmx dev.appls.cto2.paas.gsnetcloud.com
Origin http://localhost:3000
Referer http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0
```

What could be a solution?

Comment: Just a heads up, once they refresh the app, they'll have to login again, unless that's not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

`$scope.token = data.access_token;`

needs to be

`$rootScope.token = data.access_token;`

This is because `$scope` can read values assigned by `$rootScope` (`$rootScope` properties trickle down to all `$scope`s), but `$rootScope` cannot read values assigned to individual `$scope`s.